# Operations that interpret non-signaling NaNs as missing data points in Eigen

Tags: nan, eigen, convolution

In numpy, there are functions like [nanmean()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) that treat quiet NaNs as missing data, i.e. sum only over finite elements and divide by the number of finite elements. This produces quite clean and readable code.

Are there counterparts of such functions in Eigen? Currently I need to implement a masked convolution, so a masked version of dot product would help.

Comment: Is creating a copy first a good enough answer (in a one-liner, of course)?

Comment: After playing around a bit, I think that writing a (long) one-liner is harder than I originally thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like Eigen doesn't implement any of this functionality itself. In general, it looks like the best you can do is to replace NaN values with something else via `select`: for example, the following replaces elements of x less than 3 with 0

```
x = (x.array() < 3).select(0, x);
```

For a dot product, then, we can emulate `nandot` by using `select` because ignoring the nans is the same as replacing them with zeros. Using `x != x` as a check to see if `x` is `NaN`,

```
template <typename OtherDerived>
inline Scalar nandot(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other) const {
  const auto& no_nan_this = (this->array() == this->array()).select(*this, 0);
  const auto& no_nan_other = (other.array() == other.array()).select(other, 0);
  return no_nan_this.dot(no_nan_other);
}
```

This is a little convoluted looking, but it might actually be the best way to do it because of Eigen's template magic and lazy evaluation, i.e. I doubt that creating no_nan_this actually loops through the vector replacing nan's with zeros, but rather creates a wrapper object that returns the appropriate value when indexed into.

The code I put in the box above is intended to be added to the `MatrixBase` class as a plugin, so you can just call `x.nandot(y)`: put it in its own header file (say `matrix_extensions.h`) and then `#define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN "matrix_extensions.h"` before you include the Eigen headers. See http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html for more info on this.

Comment: Not exactly what I asked for, but worked for my task. Thanks!